# Cannot make Bcrypt hash to work when password is being checked back

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Bcrypt to hash passwords and using Random as per Spring documentation. I am using Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE.

I have the following OAuth2 security configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.nando.api.service.DefaultUserService" />
    <beans:bean id="webServiceClientService"
        class="com.nando.api.service.DefaultWebServiceClientService" />
    <beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="webServiceClientService" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <beans:bean id="webSecurityExpressionHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="methodSecurityExpressionHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

    <beans:bean id="tokenStore"
        class="com.nando.api.service.DefaultAccessTokenService" />

    <beans:bean id="oauthRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
        <!-- TODO arguments here -->
        <beans:constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService" ref="webServiceClientService" />
        <!-- <beans:property name="securityContextAccessor" ref="oauthRequestFactory" /> -->
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userApprovalHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <!-- TODO here -->
        <beans:property name="requestFactory" ref="oauthRequestFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager id="oauthClientAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <oauth2:authorization-server
        token-services-ref="tokenStore" client-details-service-ref="webServiceClientService"
        user-approval-page="oauth/authorize" error-page="oauth/error">
        <oauth2:authorization-code />
    </oauth2:authorization-server>

    <beans:bean id="nonceServices"
        class="com.nando.api.service.DefaultOAuthNonceService" />
    <beans:bean id="resourceServerFilter"
        class="com.nando.api.filters.OAuthSigningTokenAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <beans:property name="nonceServices" ref="nonceServices" />
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <beans:property name="resourceId" value="nando" />
    </beans:bean>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
        order="0" proxy-target-class="true">
        <expression-handler ref="methodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
    </global-method-security>

    <http security="none" pattern="/resource/**" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico" />

    <http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="oauthClientAuthenticationManager"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" pattern="/oauth/token">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="hasAuthority('OAUTH_CLIENT')" />
        <http-basic />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />
    </http>

    <http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" pattern="/services/**">
        <intercept-url pattern="/services/**"
            access="hasAuthority('USE_WEB_SERVICES')" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />
    </http>

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/session/list"
            access="hasAuthority('VIEW_USER_SESSIONS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**"
            access="hasAuthority('USE_WEB_SERVICES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login default-target-url="/ticket/list" login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/login/submit" authentication-failure-url="/login?loginFailed"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?loggedOut"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login"
            session-fixation-protection="changeSessionId">
            <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
                max-sessions="1" session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" />
        </session-management>
        <csrf />
        <expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler" />
    </http>

</beans:beans>
```

The problem is:

When it runs it goes to org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider and the method:

additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) fails because the salt is empty.

It should have a Random Salt. This is how I am creating my password and storing on the database. I have verified the retrieved password from the database and it is correct.

```
UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal();
        principal.setUserName(userName);
        UUID userID = UUIDs.timeBased();
        principal.setUserID(userID);

        String salt = BCrypt.gensalt(HASHING_ROUNDS, RANDOM);
        byte[] hash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, salt).getBytes();
        principal.setHashedPassword(Converters.byteArray2ByteBuffer(hash));
```

Where:

```
private static final SecureRandom RANDOM;

    static {
        try {
            RANDOM = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
private static final int HASHING_ROUNDS = 10;
```

The password is hashed and generated properly. It is saved properly on the database and retrieved properly. But when it gets checked, the presented password is not hashed so that the comparison fails.

First, this.saltSource is null because I have no salt beans defined. I thought this was random and the salt was the old way of doing it.

Now, when looking at the debugger:

```
if (this.saltSource != null) {
            salt = this.saltSource.getSalt(userDetails);
        }

        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");

            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
        }

        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userDetails.getPassword(), presentedPassword, salt)) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");

            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
        }
```

The presentedPassword is not hashed and the salt is empty. So the (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userDetails.getPassword(), presentedPassword, salt)) test checks and it fails.

If I am using a Random salt, how can I make this to work? What am I missing?

Comment: Looks fine to me (and the `isPasswordValid()` check should call into your `PasswordEncoder`). I'm not sure quite where you think it went wrong. Are you saying your `PasswordEncoder` is never called? How are you sure your passwords are stored correctly (what is `Converters`)? How do your `UserDetails` get the password from the `UserPrincipal` that you created?

Comment: And as you have many `<http>` blocs with not `pattern` attribute, only the first will be used ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta there's only one with no pattern (the last one)

Comment: Now I have the same problem, before I switch to using UserDetailsSerice of Spring I was using JDBC and it was working but I was not satisfied with Spring Database mode so I user the custom way to retrieve the UserEntity !